# Postgresql 11 on Lion

Tags: macos, homebrew, compatibility, postgresql

We may be receiving a 1,1 Xserve running OSX Lion 10.7.6 (newest for the hardware) and need to run Postgres on the system. Will the newest version (11.5_1 at the time of writing) work on Lion if installed via `brew`?

I understand Lion is a bit old at this point; this will be a home data base server and not one used online.

Naturally I would install brew myself and try but alas at the current point in time we do not have any computers running Lion so we have no way to check. I also looked online for "postgresql 11 system requirements" with no clear list of supported operating systems.

Additionally, as far as we are aware, this system will be running the consumer version of Lion -- aka not the special server edition.

Thank you

Comment: If [tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) doesn't run it you should be able to upgrade to El Capitan without too much bother - see https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1289279

Comment: @lx07 Ah, but alas the 1,1 Xserve is a 2006 model, stopping at Lion with unfortunately no way to upgrade the OS. Thank you for info on tiger brew. We can give that a try, however the github reveals it works with Tiger/Leopard, no mention of Lion.

Comment: Neither homebrew nor tigerbrew support lion.  I asked about it on their forum (see [here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/solved-installation-fails-with-syntax-error-on-lion/4156)) and was able to follow the linked steps (i.e. to install tigerbrew then swap to homebrew) which worked OK for me on Lion 10.7.5 in March this year.  In the end though I upgraded my mbp to El Capitain.  It is a 2007 which like yours has the 32bit EFI so you *might* also be able to force El Cap to install (I used a separate supported mac to do this) but I don't know.

Comment: @lx07 Drat. I wonder if there is a way to install an older version of brew, or possibly just install the commands we need by clicking and dragging the binaries over. Thanks for your help, it is appreciated.

Comment: I just read this page here: https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/ There is a section called 'platform support' that looks like 9.4 might be the newest supported in Lion. Hopefully there is a way around this. Additionally, I did some research on the Xserve running even Mountain lion but this is not possible :( **EDIT**: I wonder if installing via MacPorts would be better?